# Is there any issue if i am adding style continuously to label without removing the previous style?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

In my application continuously I am changing the UI depending on database values.
below is my code:
Here I am updating the UI depending on the database values.

```
 public class Lane5 implements Runnable{

     private final LSDU_MenuController lsduController;
     String dbUrl;
     public Lane(LSDU_MenuController aThis) {
     this.lsduController5 = aThis;
 }
while(true){

if(cmnd5.wim.equals("Y")){
               javafx.application.Platform.runLater( new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                lsduController.fiveWIM.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/images/Wim_T.png');-fx-background-position: center;-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat; -fx-background-color: none;");
                lsduController.logTextArea.appendText(laneNameUi+" WIM Working State  "+cmnd5.sdf.format(cmnd5.calendar.getTime())+"\n");
                }
               });
           } else {
                javafx.application.Platform.runLater( new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                lsduController.fiveWIM.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/images/Wim_T.png');-fx-background-position: center;-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat; -fx-background-color: red;");
                lsduController.logTextArea.appendText(laneNameUi+" WIM Not Working State  "+cmnd5.sdf.format(cmnd5.calendar.getTime())+"\n");
                }
               });
           }
 }
```

Here I am Calling the Lane Class:
This is my controller class

```
public class LSDU_MenuController implements Initializable {
@Override

public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
new Thread(new Lane5(this)).start();
}}
```

If I update the UI continuously like above by modifying with style sheet after some time I am getting below exception:

```
exception in thread main java.lang.outofmemoryerror java heap space
```

This one is related to JavaFx issue or my code issue.

If I update like as above that one gives this exception or not
"exception in thread main java.lang.outofmemoryerror java heap space"

Comment: I believe there is an issue in endlessly appending to a textArea. Did you make sure that this also happens with out the logging? Use a memory profiler to find out where all the memory is used/allocated!

Comment: @sebastian : if I use to clear text by using lsduController.logTextArea.clear(); then also is there any chance to get exception

Comment: You're not "adding style", you're setting the style, which will remove the previous value of the style property. So that is not causing your OOME. The code you posted will certainly cause you to run out of memory at some point because the text area is increasing indefinitely in its memory consumption. Since you have a busy while loop, you may also place so many runnables on the FX Application Thread's queue that you run out of memory that way: you will certainly cause the UI to perform extremely badly  doing this.